# Can't get rails to return from select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, submit, categories

I'm trying to set up a page where there are 4 dropdown boxes, each of which have a full list of Products. A user can select any combination of 4 products, and 'create' a new print page, which has the product information list

I only have one box right now, but when I try to create a new row for Print from this page, it doesn't return anything to :p1

new.html.erb:

```
<%= f.collection_select :p1, Product.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select One' %>

<%= f.submit "Create" %>
```

```
class PrintsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @print = Print.new
    end

    def create
        @print = Print.new(print_params)

            if @print.save
                redirect_to @print, alert: "Created successfully."
            else
                redirect_to new_print_path, alert: "Error creating print page."
            end

    end

    def show
        @print = Print.find(params[:id])

    end

    private

def print_params
    params.require(:p1).permit(:p2, :p3, :p4)
end


end
```

Model

```
class Print < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Migrate

```
class CreatePrints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :prints do |t|
      t.integer :p1
      t.integer :p2
      t.integer :p3
      t.integer :p4

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories, :products, :prints
```

I'm a total rails newbie, so I know I'm probably making a stupid mistake somewhere, but I've been fiddling with code for hours and still haven't figured out what I did wrong.

Comment: Check the content of `log/development.log` file; it could give more info about what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your print_params method is wrong :

```
def print_params
    params.require(:print).permit(:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4)
end
```

This is the right format.